# manage hosts file on Windows using Puppet

Tags: puppet, hosts, hiera

I'm trying to manage my hosts file on a Windows machine using Puppet and Hiera. My problem is that I have never really used Hiera and I'm struggling with parsing the data content into a proper format.

The relevant section in `hieradata/hiera.yaml` looks like this:

```
myhosts : [
'host1 1.2.3.4',
'host2 2.3.4.5',
'host3 3.4.5.6']
```

I have code that uses a host module, but it also depends on a class that I don't have, so naturally it doesn't work.

```
class hosts::module (
  $myhosts = hiera('myhosts'),
)
{
  define update_hosts {

    $value = split($name,' ')

    host {
      "${value[0]}" : ip => "${value[1]}",
    }
  }
  update_hosts { $myhosts :; }
}
```

I have tried using the `file` resource instead of the `host` resource, and also tried doing it without any class, but for some reason I am getting this error

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER:
Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, 
Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Duplicate
declaration: File[C:\Temp\tmp.txt] is already declared in file
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:4; cannot redeclare 
at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:4
at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:4:1
at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:10 on node puppet-agent
```

As you can see, it claims that I have a duplicate declaration, but the weird thing is that it says it has a problem with the same line. It thinks it's declaring the same thing twice for some reason.

This is the code I have now (I know it won't work but the error doesn't really sound related)

```
define hosts_update($content) {
  file { 'C:\Temp\tmp.txt' :
    ensure  => file,
    content =>  $content,
  }
}

hosts_update{ hiera('myhosts'):
content => split($name," "),
}
```

Any idea how to do this right?

Comment: The big things that initially jump out at me are that your yaml data and both Puppet snippets have syntax errors. Also, the error message pertains to your site manifest and is unrelated to this code you are showing, so please show us that code instead.

Comment: This is the code.

Comment: You put a define inside a class inside your `site.pp`?

Comment: lol yes,  it wasn't there at first this was the last attempt

Comment: ok i'll rephrase my question can any one pleas walk me through what i need to do to make it work you can ignore the code i have. i just need to understand how to do it on windows on linux it works great

Answer (score 0):

fixed it.

site.pp

```
include update_hosts
```

init.pp

```
class update_hosts::host
(
  $hosts = hiera('hosts_list'),
)
{
        update_host { $hosts :; }
}
```

host.pp

```
define update_host {
​
    $value = split($name,' ')
​
    host {
                "${value[0]}" : ip => "${value[1]}",
                target => "C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts"
        }
}
```